# Difference between SafeProcessHandle and IntPtr for an API call

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, handle, intptr

While working with WinAPI, I decided to implement a call to [GetProcessAfinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683213%28VS.85%29.aspx) in my C# application. However, I've seen two different signatures for this function.

One of them uses `SafeProcessHandle` for the handle:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool GetProcessAffinityMask(SafeProcessHandle handle, out IntPtr processMask, out IntPtr systemMask);
```

The other possible version ([on P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetProcessAffinityMask.html)) uses `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetProcessAffinityMask(IntPtr hProcess,
   out UIntPtr lpProcessAffinityMask, out UIntPtr lpSystemAffinityMask);
```

Given that both functions return the same values, what is the difference between passing a `SafeProcessHandle` instance or `IntPtr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Safe Handles and Critical Finalization MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fh21e17c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is describing this difference.